# Running additional copies of Windows in a VM Licensing

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, licensing

Can I run additional copies of Windows as guest VM's legally using the license on the host machine (the idea behind this is to isolate my main computer from bugs in shell extension code under development)? I'm intrested in both a Windows 7 Home Premium x64 machine and a Windows 7 Pro x64 machine.

I searched around on the internet a bit and couldn't find anything on the legality of it, just various bits on how to actually do it and digging through all that licensing smallprint isnt exactly my thing :(